# Is There Any Python Library for PTC Integrity LM Clint Control ( in perspective of handling, uploading & Downloading Documents)

Tags: python, command-line-interface, ui-automation, ptc-windchill

I have beet working on creating a automated Program for Merging the Python and PTC Integrity LM Clint
the program should work as fallows :
Program RUN
***`Ask For Document ID for PTC`

`Open The Document`

`Get Document Content`

`Print the Content`

`Get the changes from the User and Update the Documents`

`Close the Document`

`Upload the changed Document in the PTC again.`***

Now while doing Some research I know that there is one way to handle the Clint using the Command prompt , I have found the CIL Command lists For the Control of clint, So we can definitely use Subprocess Lib from the python and that's why I was curios if there is already Existing Library for Python or not. otherwise then i'll have to create it My self.